# Length of a plane curve

Tags: definite-integrals

> Find the length of the curve
>   $$x = t - sin\,t, \quad\quad y = 1 - cos\,t,  \quad\quad 0\leq t\leq 2\pi$$

I have gotten close to the solution, but clearly I am making an error because I arrive at 0 for the answer.
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=1-cos\,t, \quad \frac{dy}{dt}=sin\,t$$
$$L_{0}^{2\pi}= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1-cos \,t)^2+ (sin\,t)^2}\quad dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-2\,cos\,t+cos^2t + sin^2t}\quad dt$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\,cos\,t}\quad dt$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}(-2)(\sqrt{1+\,cos\,t})]_0^{2\pi}$$
$$=\frac{-4}{\sqrt2}(\sqrt{1+\,cos\,t})]_0^{2\pi}$$
$$=-4-(-4)=0$$
When I plot the parametric function, as well as the final antiderivative, I can see that I am on the right track with the sum of 4s, but the sign seems to be a problem (plus the plot of the antiderivative is negative with a cusp at $\pi$ that doesn't seem like it is right).

UPDATE/REPLY:
Thanks for the pointers and the solution to this.  However, I'm not sure why my antiderivative is wrong?   If I take the derivative of the solution, I get back the integral function:
$$\frac{d}{dt} (-2)(\sqrt{1+cos\,t)}$$
$$=-\frac{-sin\,t}{\sqrt{(1+cos\,t)}}$$
$$=\frac{sin\,t}{\sqrt{(1+cos\,t)}}\frac{(\sqrt{(1-cos\,t)}}{(\sqrt{(1-cos\,t)}}$$
$$=\frac{sin\,t*\sqrt{1-cos\,t}}{\sqrt{1-cos^2\,t}}$$
$$=\frac{sin\,t*\sqrt{1-cos\,t}}{\sqrt{sin^2\,t}}$$
$$=\sqrt{1-cos\,t}$$
If that is correct, then why doesn't it work for determining length?

Comment: $\sqrt{\sin^2t}=\sin t$ only when $t<\pi$

Comment: @Empy2 - Thanks!  That explains it - it works to give the positive length of 4 for range of 0 to pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing(mostly) from your work:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=1-\cos\,t, \quad \frac{dy}{dt}=\sin\,t$$
$$L_{0}^{2\pi}= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1-\cos \,t)^2+ (\sin\,t)^2}\quad dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-2\,\cos\,t+\cos^2t + \sin^2t}\quad dt$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\,\cos\,t}\quad dt$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(\sqrt{2})\sin(\frac{t}{2}) dt$$
$$=2\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\sin(\frac{t}{2})dt$$
$$=2\cdot -2\cos(\frac{t}{2})\big|_{0}^{2\pi}$$
$$=4\big(\cos(0)-\cos(\pi))$$
$$=8$$

Comment: +1, but check the sudden change from $\sqrt{1-\cos t}$ to $\sqrt 2 \sin \frac x 2$ changing from $t$ to $x.$

Comment: @AntoniParellada Sorry , fixed it. I was also answering another question so got lost :)

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is wrong. You should arrive at:

$$\int \sqrt{1-\cos(t)} =  -2 \sqrt{1 - \cos(t)} \cot\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right) $$

Hint: $$1 - \cos(t) = 2 \sin^2\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)$$